# Need help to understand while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I started to learn python and I am doing small projects to help in my day to day activities. Now I am trying the following script to calculate seconds like a countdown - 314 seconds on every for, but I don't understand how to get the new value:

```
counter = 1
currenttime = 2000
while counter <=5:
    counter = counter + 1
    newtime = currenttime - 314
    print arty
```

In this case, it starts with 2000 - 314, it prints the newtime 1686, but now I want the next calculation to be with the new currenttime (1686 - 314) and keep going.

Comment: You don't have a for loop, you have a while loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So change `newtime = currenttime - 314` to `currenttime = currenttime - 314`:

```
counter = 1
currenttime = 2000
while counter <= 5:
    counter = counter + 1             # or counter += 1
    currenttime = currenttime - 314   # or currenttime -= 314
    print currenttime
```

outputs:

```
# 1686
# 1372
# 1058
# 744
# 430
```

Comment: oh my god, it didn't cross my mind! Thank you so much, it all makes sense now :P

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps your case :

```
counter = 1
currenttime = 2000
while counter <=5:
    counter += 1
    currenttime -= 314
    print currenttime
```

if you need a counter using a for loop:

```
max_count = 5
currenttime = 2000
for counter in range(max_count):
    currenttime -= 314
    print currenttime
```